# ReferenceError: SockJS is not defined, could not import module into Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, sockjs

I am using Angular 1.5.11 and I am using sockjs & stomp for connecting to a web socket. The Angular project has a bower dependency for stomp and sockjs-client, but when I use

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8999/socket-app');
```

I get an error saying 'SockJS' is not defined. I use gulp for the build and serve. Do I have to explicitly declare or export this somewhere in the project?

The same thing works when I put all my code in a simple single file html with sockjs and angular code.

My directory structure below:

[image]

Edit: To add more details, I have the following bower dependencies:

[image]

After bower install, I see them in the components folder. so I have the dependencies required, but I guess something is still missing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing the same issue using an npm install of sockjs-client and importing like so: import {SockJS} from 'sockjs-client';

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what you need is sockjs-client, not sockjs. Try install with bower sockjs-client